# Entity Framework share linked table through inheritance is possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Using Entity Framework Code first, I have several entities that share some fields, so I've created a base entity:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : EntityBase
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product : EntityBase
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now lets say that I want to provide a table for related images or attachments if you prefer, to those (and more of this) tables. An entity defined like:

```
public class Attachment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    //For linking?
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }

    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way of adding this relation to EntityBase so every entity that inherites it has a relation to the table and navigation properties?
I've spent hours on this and I hadn't found a way for it to work.

---

Edit: It finally happened not being possible as per v 1.1.1 Entity Framework Core does not support inheritance as I thought about it and it focuses it as a Table per Hierarchy representation of the DB: [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/…](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the list of attachment to the base class, and a reference and referring id to the attachments. This works:

```
public class Attachment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }

    public byte[] Content { get; set; } 

    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityBase Parent { get; set; }
}
public class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : EntityBase
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product : EntityBase
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the database schema generated from this model (you can see that the default TPH inheritance works by convention):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Akos for your response. Unfortunately the inheritance does not work like this and then it does not create the two Customers / Products tables and intead creates an EntityBase one. I'm using EF Core and MYSQL database if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `Attachment` cannot have a foreign key to either `Customer` or `Product`. The FK can point only to one table. So you need a common table where the FK can point to. One solution is shown above, where the one common table holds all the information for the entities in the inheritance tree (TPH inheritance).

The other solution is to use TPT inheritance. You still need a common table, where the FK can point to. That will be the `EntityBases` table. And then you can create two other tables, one for the Customer and one for the Product entity, which will use their own FK to refer to the correspoing `EntityBases` (through which, you can associate your attachments).

Whether this works or not depends on the actual EF-MySQL provider you are using. But **if** it is supported, here's a way you can configure it:

```
 public class Attachment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }

    public byte[] Content { get; set; } 

    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityBase Parent { get; set; }
}
public class EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : EntityBase
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product : EntityBase
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyCtx : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Products");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customers");
    }
}
```

This will result in a different schema than before:

[image]

Comment: It seems that Entity Framework Core does not support inheritance as I thought about it and it focuses it as a Table per Hierarchy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance
So I suppose this is not possible. I'll create a new question for the "common table relation" but for normal independant tables.